# How to use system wide semaphores on Linux?

Tags: linux, semaphore

I already read the following 2 posts:

- [When to call sem_unlink()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15164484/when-to-call-sem-unlink)
- [System-wide global variable / semaphore / mutex in C++/Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32338732/system-wide-global-variable-semaphore-mutex-in-c-linux)

But both don't really help me understanding how to make proper use of the semaphores in Linux.

What I want to achieve is e.g. finding out if the current process is the last process having a file open or how many processes have a certain shared object in memory right now from within that very same shared object.

I thought a named Semaphore would be the way to go and on Windows this works like a charm. On Linux however I am facing the challenge of knowing the proper moment to call sem_unlink which is discussed in the first link from above. I understood the behaviour but I would still argue the function is rather unusable for my scenario. Since I don't know when certain processes loading my library are being started it might happen that after a process has terminated another one starts and this one again shall use the very same lock, thus I cannot call sem_unlink when the first process dies (assuming at least one more continues to execute). I can neither call sem_unlink when the last process dies since I never know which one is the last.

This comes from the fact that sem_getvalue and sem_post are 2 separate functions and therefore not an atomic operation like ReleaseSemaphore on Windows. Therefore when sem_getvalue tells me that there are no more usages this information might be outdated/incorrect already once I call sem_unlink then...

Am I missing something? Or maybe this can even be done without a semaphore?

Comment: You want to destroy the semaphore when you destroy the resource it protects. If the resource is persistent, so is the semaphore. Just don't unlink it.

Comment: Thanks! Thing is I don't really get what happens with the counter of the Semaphore in that case but I guess I need to do some experiments to find out if it is properly decremented/incremented e.g. if a process crashes while holding it. But when thinking about this is doesn't really seem to relate to the sem_unlink call...