# shm_open not setting group write access

Tags: linux, file-permissions, shared-memory

I am creating a new shared memory object like so

```
  int fd = shm_open("somekey", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
```

The return value is fine and I expect to find something like the following in /dev/shm

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 root   group     4096 Jun 27 19:08 somekey
```

but instead the write access in the files are missing and I don't know why.

```
-rwxr-x--- 1 root   group     4096 Jun 27 19:08 somekey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is duplicate of below thread

[POSIX shared memory and semaphores permissions set incorrectly by open calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909505/posix-shared-memory-and-semaphores-permissions-set-incorrectly-by-open-calls)

```
mode_t old_umask = umask(0);

int fd = shm_open("somekey", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);

// restore old
umask(old_umask);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html

> the object's permission bits are set according to the low-order 9 bits of *mode*, except that those bits set in the process file mode creation mask (see [umask(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html)) are cleared for the new object.

It's just umask doing its job, the same way it does for a regular `open`.